# Yocto:Execute shell script inside my source repository environment (inside downloads folder ?)

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

in Yocto I need to execute a bash script that depends on the source repository environment. My current approach is to execute the script directly in the downloads folder.

Pseudocode (hope you know what I mean):

```
do_patch_append () {
    os.system(' \
        pushd ${DL_DIR}/svn/*/svn/myapp/Src; \
        dos2unix ./VersionBuild/MakeVersionList.sh; \
        ./VersionBuild/MakeVersionList.sh ${S}/Src/VersionList.h; \
        popd \
        ')
}
```

Before I start fiddling with the details: Is this a valid approach ? And is do_patch the right place ?

Reason: The script MakeVersionList.sh generates a header file containing revision info from subversion. It executes "svn info" on several folders and parses its output into the header file VersionList.h, which will later be accessed in ${S} during compilation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because the information seem to be used during compilation only, you could use do_compile_preprend() instead or do_configure_append()

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for giving helpful advice. Here's how I finally did it. To minimize dependencies to server infrastructure (SVN server) I put the version generation into do_fetch. I had to do a manual do_unpack as well, because adding the generated file to SRC_URI (like ${DL_DIR}/svn/...) made the fetcher try to fetch it.

```
#
# Build bitstone application
#

SUMMARY = "Bitstone mega wallet"
SECTION = "Rockefeller"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=bbea815ee2795b2f4230826c0c6b8814"

#Register for root file system aggregation
APP_NAME = "bst-wallet"
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/${APP_NAME}"

PV = "${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SVN_SRV = "flints-svn"
SRC_URI = "svn://${SVN_SRV}/svn/${APP_NAME};module=Src;protocol=http;user=fred;pswd=pebbles "

S = "${WORKDIR}/Src"
GEN_FILE = "VersionList.h"

do_fetch_append () {
    os.system(' \
        cd ./svn/{0}/svn/{1}/Src; \
        TZ=Pacific/Yap ./scripts/MakeVersionList.sh {2}; \
        '.format(d.getVar("SVN_SRV"), d.getVar("APP_NAME"), d.getVar("GEN_FILE"))
        )
}

do_unpack_append () {
    os.system(' \
        cp {3}/svn/{0}/svn/{1}/Src/{2} {4} \
        '.format(d.getVar("SVN_SRV"), d.getVar("APP_NAME"), d.getVar("GEN_FILE"), \
                 d.getVar("DL_DIR"), d.getVar("S")) \
        )
}

do_install_append () {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 ${APP_NAME} ${D}${bindir}/
}
```